# SQLAlchemy join onto an inline table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an inline defined table:

```
select(
    Values(column('key', String), column('value', String), column('ordering', Integer), name='subq')
    .data([(e.name, e.value, i) for i, e in enumerate(DurationType)])
```

This produces this SQL:

```
select key, value, ordering 
from (values ("key1", "name1", 1), ("key2", "name2", 2) ...)
```

Which is a fine table:
[image]

Now i need to join this subquery to another one. The other query is:

```
self.session.query(self.model)
                .filter(self.model.duration != None)
                .with_entities(
                duration_bucket := case((self.model.duration < 60, DurationType.LESS_THAN_1.name),
                                        (and_(60 <= self.model.duration, self.model.duration < 60 * 5),
                                         DurationType.FROM_1_TO_5.name),
                                        (and_(60 * 5 <= self.model.duration,
                                              self.model.duration < 60 * 10), DurationType.FROM_5_TO_10.name),
                                        (and_(60 * 10 <= self.model.duration,
                                              self.model.duration < 60 * 20), DurationType.FROM_10_TO_20.name),
                                        (and_(60 * 20 <= self.model.duration,
                                              self.model.duration < 60 * 30), DurationType.FROM_20_TO_30.name),
                                        (60 * 30 <= self.model.duration, DurationType.MORE_THAN_30.name)
                                        ).label('id'))
                .group_by(duration_bucket)
                .having(count() > 0)
```

Which is apart from `case` clause is just a select from aggregation, that leaves me with a result of single column `"id"`

But for the life of me I can't figure how to join it. My initial attempt looked like this:

```
inline_enum_table = select(
    Values(column('key', String), column('value', String), column('ordering', Integer), name="suqb")
    .data([(e.name, e.value, i) for i, e in enumerate(DurationType)])).subquery()

inline_enum_table = self.session.query(inline_enum_table)
return (
    self.session.query(self.model)
        .filter(self.model.duration != None)
        .with_entities(
        duration_bucket := case((self.model.duration < 60, DurationType.LESS_THAN_1.name),
                                (and_(60 <= self.model.duration, self.model.duration < 60 * 5),
                                 DurationType.FROM_1_TO_5.name),
                                (and_(60 * 5 <= self.model.duration,
                                      self.model.duration < 60 * 10), DurationType.FROM_5_TO_10.name),
                                (and_(60 * 10 <= self.model.duration,
                                      self.model.duration < 60 * 20), DurationType.FROM_10_TO_20.name),
                                (and_(60 * 20 <= self.model.duration,
                                      self.model.duration < 60 * 30), DurationType.FROM_20_TO_30.name),
                                (60 * 30 <= self.model.duration, DurationType.MORE_THAN_30.name)
                                ).label('id'))
        .group_by(duration_bucket)
        .having(count() > 0)
        .join(duration_enum := inline_enum_table.label('qwe'), duration_enum.key == duration_bucket)
```

This particular attempt results in `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Expected mapped entity or selectable/table as join target`

I've had many more tries with all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following to work. `select().subquery()` is what helps SQLAlchemy work with such objects as part of a FROM clause.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, column, create_engine, Integer, join, select, String, values
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session

engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")
Base = declarative_base()


class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "thing"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    key = Column(String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Thing(id={repr(self.id)}, key={repr(self.key)})"


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as sess, sess.begin():
    sess.add_all(
        [
            Thing(id=1, key="key1"),
            Thing(id=2, key="key2"),
        ]
    )

inline_enum_table = select(
    values(
        column("key", String),
        column("value", String),
        column("ordering", Integer),
        name="inline_enums",
        literal_binds=True,
    ).data(
        [
            ("key1", "name1", 1),
            ("key2", "name2", 2),
        ]
    )
).subquery()

with Session(engine) as sess:
    query = select(Thing, inline_enum_table.c.value).select_from(
        join(Thing, inline_enum_table, Thing.key == inline_enum_table.c.key)
    )
    print(query)
    """
    SELECT thing.id, thing.key, anon_1.value 
    FROM thing JOIN (SELECT inline_enums.key AS key, inline_enums.value AS value, inline_enums.ordering AS ordering 
    FROM (VALUES ('key1', 'name1', 1), ('key2', 'name2', 2)) AS inline_enums (key, value, ordering)) AS anon_1 ON thing.key = anon_1.key
    """

    results = sess.execute(query).all()
    print(results)
    # [(Thing(id=1, key='key1'), 'name1'), (Thing(id=2, key='key2'), 'name2')]
```